# change sidebar height by page length

Tags: html, css, webshop

I am building a webshop with on the left side a sidebar with a sort of navbar in it.
But the background (color Brown) has to fill the whole left side, but if my page is longer it covers not the complete left side.

This is my CSS for the background:

```
.sidebar {
    z-index:            10;
    border-top:         2px #000000; 
    position:           absolute; 
    float:              left; 
    left:               0; 
    margin-top:         -5%; 
    padding-bottom:     -10px; 
    width:              15%; 
    min-height:         115%;
    max-height:         200%;
    background:         #C6A970;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to cover the left side of my webpage?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: a jsfiddle would help you and us to debug

Comment: you will either need to use CSS hacks to make the sidebar extend to the bottom or javascript

Comment: Without context it's hard to debug, but you can try to use `min-height: 100vh;` on your sidebar to at least fill the viewport.

Comment: There not some usefull code extra. Only an ul with li items (x 16) in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the informations you gave you probably search something like that:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uqLnsk2L/)

Your provided css already shows that your code must be messy, using `float` and `position absolute` together is weird and your `min-height` and `max-height` are over `100%`.

We could help a little better if you provide full code.

Comment: Yes that's what I am looking for. Float was useless in my code, so I deleted it now. The problem is, the sidebar stops somewhere in the middle of my webpage. So there still is a white bar at it. One more problem is that every page has a variable height...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Use this css:

```
   .sidebar {
        z-index:            10;
        border-top:         2px #000000; 
        position:           absolute; 
        float:              left; 
        left:               0;
        bottom:             0; 
        margin-top:         -5%; 
        padding-bottom:     -10px; 
        width:              15%; 
        min-height:         100%;
        background:         #C6A970;
    }
```

or refer to the jsfiddle link below:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/89f074ke/1/
```